# Why does traffic continue to flow through my gateway despite a firewall rule blocking all outbound traffic addressed to it?

Tags: routing, firewall, kvm, qemu, ufw

While messing around in a qemu guest I discovered something very peculiar. If I set the system firewall to reject all traffic to my gateway (`10.0.2.2`), the firewall only rejects traffic destined to the gateway directly. Traffic not destined to `10.0.2.2` seemingly continues to get routed and flows through the gateway as if the rule wasn't there at all.

As I understand it from the perspective of the guest (`10.0.2.15`):

```
Packet{dest==10.0.2.0/24}   10.0.2.15  -x->  10.0.2.2                (Rejected)
Packet{dest!=10.0.2.0/24}   10.0.2.15  <-->  10.0.2.2  <-> !=10.0.2.0/24 (Okay)
```

This is completely contrary to what I expected. I assume there is something I'm missing but I don't know what.

Here is my setup:

- Firewall Rule:

  ```
  ufw reject out to 10.0.2.0/24
  ```
- Output of `ip route`:

  ```
  default via 10.0.2.2 dev ens3 proto dhcp metric 100 
  10.0.2.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
  ```
- The relevant part of output of `iptables -S` seems to be:

  ```
  -A ufw-user-output -d 10.0.2.0/24 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working and not blocked because a gateway routes packets with source and destination IP addresses that *are not* the gateway's address. No **IPv4** packet (see later about ARP) with address 10.0.2.2 is used to successfully route through the gateway with IP address 10.0.2.2/24.

So when 10.0.2.15 sends a packet to 8.8.8.8 this packet has source 10.0.2.15 and destination 8.8.8.8. This packet has no destination 10.0.2.2 and thus no destination within 10.0.2.0/24: pass.

The only packets with the IPv4 address 10.0.2.2 in their payload indirectly involved with routing through the gateway are not IPv4 packets. They are [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) packets used by the VM system to discover (and cache in its ARP table) the Ethernet MAC address of the gateway's interface. IPv4 traffic for "outside": matching the route with the gateway, is then sent at the link layer (Ethernet) to this MAC address (and not to the IP address 10.0.2.2).

ARP is not filtered by *iptables* which is the backend of UFW, so can't be blocked with UFW. It could be with [*arptables*](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/arptables-nft.8) for example, but useful use case is not very common.

---

Notes

- DHCP (IPv4)

  If 10.0.2.2 is also a DHCP server to the VMs this might possibly or not (depending on the exact technology in use) prevent at some point later DHCP communication to work properly or force the VM to do a broadcast DHCP DISCOVER instead of an unicast DHCP REQUEST. If the lease were to be lost possibly a few hours later, so would the IP address and thus routes and thus indirectly the connectivity through the router.

  Usually that's not the case, because usually DHCP on Linux has to rely on RAW sockets (for example to handle source address 0.0.0.0 properly) which bypass all of *iptables* rules.
- IPv6

  As the link layer resolution protocol for IPv6 is not ARP but [using ICMPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol), thus part of IPv6 and filtered by *ip6tables*, some assumptions valid for IPv4 are not valid for IPv6. For example indiscriminately blocking ICMPv6 usually results in very fast loss of IPv6 connectivity and removal of routable IPv6 address acquired through [SLAAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Stateless_address_autoconfiguration_.28SLAAC.29), while blocking indiscriminately ICMP for IPv4 usually works fine (beside possible [PMTUD blackhole problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery#Problems)).